# How Prometheus logical operator evaluated?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-operator

I have two query that combined by logical operator "And".
Let's suppose query structure is like as follows,

> (QueryA > 0) and (queryB > 100)

From C/C++ we know that, If first operand is true then logical operator check for 2nd operand. If first operand is false, then it does not check for 2nd operand.

Does it also true for Prometheus query language?

Comment: No, it works differently. See https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators

In short, in response you'll get series `QueryA` which values are `>0` and their labels are matching labels from `queryB > 100`  expression result. 
Both queries will be executed.

Comment: I don't know if Prometheus does any matching optimisations. For example, it could copy filters from query A to query B, so it can transform query`my_metricA{foo="bar"} > 0 and my_metricB > 0` to `my_metricA{foo="bar"} > 0 and my_metricB{foo="bar"} > 0` in order to make the search faster.

Comment: FYI, VictoriaMetrics performs this optimization before query execution - see [this example](https://play.victoriametrics.com/promql/expand-with-exprs?query=my_metricA%7Bfoo%3D%22bar%22%7D+%3E+0+and+my_metricB+%3E+0&commit=Expand)